# How can I know which API level I am using with Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, api, android-viewpager

I am wondering how can I know which API level I am using with my ADT. I posted a question about an error that occurred when I was trying to run a sample app source codes which use a `View` (http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Animations.zip). Someone asked me which API level I am using? So how do I know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make an Android app, you have to choose the minimum API level. You can check this in the first lines of your manifest.

You can check the API level of an android device under Settings->about phone. This will give you the Android version number (which is not the same as the API level).
You can look for the API level [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) when you have the version number.

If you want to get it programatically you will have to do something like this:

```
Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK library is included in the project when you create a project. From there you can find out which OS version you are using and from that the api level.
If you are in eclipse and ADT is installed then right click on the project and go to properties. There select Android in resources. You can find the API level corresponding to the target OS version.